# Restoring system databases on Availability group replicas

Tags: sql-server-2014, restore, availability-groups, system-databases

I'll start this off by saying I'm very new to availability groups.

Looking at information on availability groups, it looks like you can't add system databases to a group. MSDN seems to indicate that we should manually replicate logins, jobs, etc.

Are there any consequences of restoring system databases from backups taken on a primary replica to a secondary replica in an availability group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your server configuration is stored in the master database along with your users logins so I wouldn't recommend restoring the master database from the primary.

As for copying users and jobs, have a look at [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) . Its a set of Powershell tools that include ones for copying users and jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew, I'll definitely take a look at your link. I wanted to clarify your comment on server configuration. Will this make a difference if we want to have two identical servers? If we have the same server level configurations and keep the databases in the same file locations, would it still be unwise to restore master?

Or should we just be wary of restore master, because just in case some thing changes on the primary server, we would screw up the instance on the secondary?

Comment: Actually I see that the master also stores endpoint information and this is not something that we probably want replicated as it may screw up Availability Groups perhaps.

Comment: I would say that even if everything else was identical, the server name help in master won't be. I've done by initially using tools such as the ones in the link (I actually wrote my own) and then manually maintained them afterwards. I decided to do it like that as after the initial migration, jobs and users don't change very often.